# Moving (by van) from Switzerland to UK - Need any EU transit documents?

Tags: eu, relocation

I plan to move from Switzerland to the UK. I plan to hire a "van with a man" style moving company (much cheaper than a "professional" moving company). I know that I (or they / the driver) requires a UK ToR1 form and a packing list.

However I've heard from some places that I also need some form of EU transit documents for EU customs inspection, as the driver will obviously have to drive through the EU (France) to get to the UK. But I was not able to find out anything online, and the embassy couldn't help. I also tried to pass the ball back to the moving company but as they are a rather cheap-ish style and not a professional "full service" company, I want to make sure of my own.

Any help or pointer would be appreciated.